# Most efficient way to assign values to maps

Tags: c++, dictionary, stdmap, std

Which way to assign values to a map is most efficient? Or are they all optimized to the same code (on most modern compilers)?

```
   // 1) Assignment using array index notation
   Foo["Bar"] = 12345;

   // 2) Assignment using member function insert() and STL pair
   Foo.insert(std::pair<string,int>("Bar", 12345));

   // 3) Assignment using member function insert() and "value_type()"
   Foo.insert(map<string,int>::value_type("Bar", 12345));

   // 4) Assignment using member function insert() and "make_pair()"
   Foo.insert(std::make_pair("Bar", 12345));
```

(I know I could benchmark and check compiler output, but this question arose now and the only thing I have close at hand is my mobile phone... hehe)

Comment: I would bet on `they are all the same`. I could elaborate on why one would be faster than the other but that would be only if we ignore compiler optimizations.

Comment: @BoPersson: actually, `4)` works, `std::pair<std::string, int> p = std::make_pair("Bar", 12345);` because the constructor of `pair` is permissive that way (as long as the types can be converted, it works).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First, there are semantic differences between `[]` and `insert`:

- `[]` will **replace** the old value (if any)
- `insert` will **ignore** the new value (if an old value is already present)

therefore comparing the two is useless in general.

Regarding the inserts versions:

- `std::map<std::string, int>::value_type` **is** `std::pair<std::string const, int>` so no (important) difference between 3 and 4
- `std::make_pair("Bar", 12345)` is cheaper than `std::pair<std::string, int>("Bar", 12345)` because the `std::string` type is a full fledged class with operations to do on copy and `"Bar"` is just a string literal (thus just a pointer copy); however since at the end you do need to create the `std::string`... it will depend on the quality of your compiler

In general, I would recommend:

- `[]` for updating
- `insert(std::make_pair())` for ignoring duplicates

`std::make_pair` is not only shorter, it also respects the DRY guideline: Don't Repeat Yourself.

---

For completeness though, the fastest (and easiest) would be [`emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) (C++11 enabled):

```
map.emplace("Bar", 12345);
```

Its behavior is that of `insert`, but it constructs the new element in-place.

Comment: I'm well aware of the fact that `[]`will replace any existing value. The same holds true for this notation on most data structures. So I was thinking a clean map and just inserting a single value. But since the others actually do keep track of whether or not an old value exists I would guess that there must be some additional code generated for that purpose. Thus making them different from `[]`.

Comment: @inquam: `[]` is prone to be a little slower because it involves building an empty value and immediately discarding it... however this is only a problem if building the empty value is slow in the first place (obviously).

Comment: @inquam: A typical implementation for `insert` will: 1) use internal find functions to get the tree node, if any 2) if it exists, return that else 3) use the result of the find to insert the new value and return that. An implementation for `operator[]` will do the exact same thing except 3) inserts a default constructed value and returns that. (You then overwrite whatever was returned.)

Comment: `std::map<std::string, int>::value_type` is `std::pair<const std::string, int>`, not `std::pair<std::string, int>`. Therefore only 3) has a type which can be directly inserted without an additional type conversion (or the overhead of `[]`). This overhead might be removed by the compiler, but in general I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: @Grizzly: if we go this road, `emplace` is even better -> in-place construction only when necessary.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: That is of course always the preferable options, but that wasn't one of the options given in the question ;). Besides at least gcc doesn't have a working `emplace` for associative containers yet, so it might not be an option.

Comment: @Grizzly: It does not really matter whether 3 has a type that exactly matches the type stored in the map, but rather what the cost of insertion is, and that is mentioned in the answer. As a matter of fact the lack of conversion might actually be counter productive, as you can move out of a non-const `std::string`, but I am not sure whether you are allowed to move out of a `const std::string`, and that could imply that 3) might have a higher cost in a C++11 compiler.

Comment: "it also respects the DRY guideline: Don't Repeat Yourself." - You repeated yourself on purpose, right :)

Answer (score 2):

1) may be slightly slower than the other methods because `std::map::operator[]` first default-creates the object if it doesn't already exist, then returns a reference that you can use `operator=` on to set your desired value, i.e. two operations.

2-4) should be equivalent since `map::value_type` is a typedef to `std::pair` for the same types, and therefore `make_pair` is also equivalent. The compiler should treat these identically.

Also note that performance can be increased further if you need to both check for existence (e.g. to perform special logic depending on whether it exists or not) and then also insert it, by using `map::lower_bound` to first get a hint to where the element should be, so `map::insert` does not have to search the whole `map` again:

```
 // get the iterator to where the key *should* be if it existed:
 std::map::iterator hint = mymap.lower_bound(key);

 if (hint == mymap.end() || mymap.key_comp()(key, hint->first)) {
     // key didn't exist in map
     // special logic A here...

     // insert at the correct location
     mymap.insert(hint, make_pair(key, new_value));
 } else { 
     // key exists in map already
     // special logic B here...

     // just update value
     hint->second = new_value;
 }
```

Comment: Should there be ! before mymap.key_comp()(key, hint->first) ?

Comment: @ManoharReddyPoreddy no; `mymap.key_comp()(key, hint->first)` checks whether `key` is less than `hint->first`. If `true`, that means `key` was not present (since `lower_bound` returns an iterator to the first element not less). `false` would mean that `key` is identical to `hint->first`.

Comment: It's bit confusing. lower_bound can give >=, not < does not imply == or !=, so, wouldn't you require mymap.key_comp()(key, hint->first) && mymap.key_comp()(hint->first, key) or similar?

Comment: I agree it's confusing at first. Like you say, `lower_bound` returns an iterator to an existing element that is either *equal* to or *larger* than the supplied `key` meaning `hint->first < key` would always be `false`; there's no need to check this. Instead, just checking `key < hint->first` allows us to confirm if the returned iterator is *equal* (`(key < hint->first) == false`) or *larger* (`(key < hint->first) == true`), i.e. whether `key` already exists in the map or not. This covers all cases.

Comment: Actually I lost context in last few days since I am working on other things. I quickly checked, none of the top 5 links have used it as a value to compare, but as a range in while http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/key_comp/  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cpp_standard_library/cpp_multimap_key_comp.htm , I am not saying you wrong, but I can't see what you are saying clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Your first possibility: `Foo["Bar"] = 12345;` has somewhat different semantics than the others -- it'll insert a new object if none exists (like the others) but *overwrite* the current contents if none exists (where the others using `insert` will fail if that key is already present).

As far as speed goes, it has the potential to be slower than the others. When you're inserting a new object, it has create a pair with the specified key and a default-constructed value_type, then assign the correct value_type afterwards. The others all construct the pair the correct key and value and insert that object. Being fair, however, my experience is that the difference is rarely significant (with older compilers, it was more significant, but with newer ones pretty minimal).

The next two are equivalent to each other. You're just using two different ways to name the same type. By run-time, there's no difference between them at all.

The fourth uses a template function (make_pair) that theoretically *could* involve an extra level of function call. I'd be quite surprised to see a real difference from this though, except (possibly) if you were careful to ensure that the compiler did absolutely *no* optimization (especially inlining) at all.

Bottom line: The first will often be a little slower than the rest (but not always and not by much). The other three will almost always be equal (as in: normally expect any reasonable compiler to produce identical code for all three) even though there's theoretical justification for the fourth being slower.

Answer (score 1):

Even though there has been a couple of good answers already I thought I might as well do a quick benchmark. Ran each one 5 million times and used c++11's chrono to measure the time it took.

Heres the code:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdio>

// 5 million
#define times 5000000

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5;
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point timeStart, timeEnd;
    int x = 0;

    // 1) Assignment using array index notation
    timeStart = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (x = 0; x <= times; x++)
    {
        foo1[std::to_string(x)] = 12345;
    }
    timeEnd = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    printf("1) took %i milliseconds\n", (unsigned long long)std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(timeEnd-timeStart).count());

    // 2) Assignment using member function insert() and STL pair
    timeStart = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (x = 0; x <= times; x++)
    {
        foo2.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>(std::to_string(x), 12345));
    }
    timeEnd = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    printf("2) took %i milliseconds\n", (unsigned long long)std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(timeEnd-timeStart).count());

    // 3) Assignment using member function insert() and "value_type()"
    timeStart = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (x = 0; x <= times; x++)
    {
        foo3.insert(std::map<std::string, int>::value_type(std::to_string(x), 12345));
    }
    timeEnd = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    printf("3) took %i milliseconds\n", (unsigned long long)std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(timeEnd-timeStart).count());

    // 4) Assignment using member function insert() and "make_pair()"
    timeStart = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (x = 0; x <= times; x++)
    {
        foo4.insert(std::make_pair(std::to_string(x), 12345));
    }
    timeEnd = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    printf("4) took %i milliseconds\n", (unsigned long long)std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(timeEnd-timeStart).count());

    // 5) Matthieu M.'s suggestion of C++11's emplace
    timeStart = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (x = 0; x <= times; x++)
    {
        foo5.emplace(std::to_string(x), 12345);
    }
    timeEnd = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    printf("5) took %i milliseconds\n", (unsigned long long)std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(timeEnd-timeStart).count());

    return 0;
}
```

The output for 5 million iterations is:

```
1) took 23448 milliseconds
2) took 22854 milliseconds
3) took 22372 milliseconds
4) took 22988 milliseconds
5) took 21356 milliseconds
```

GCC version:

```
g++ (Built by MinGW-builds project) 4.8.0 20121225 (experimental)
```

My machine:

```
Intel i5-3570k overclocked at 4.6 GHz
```

**EDIT1: Fixed the code and redid the benchmark.**

**EDIT2: Added Matthieu M.'s suggestion for C++11's emplace and he is right, emplace is fastest**

Comment: Neat... but wrong. Note that the `insert` versions here will never actually insert, whereas the `[]` version always assign. So this is screwed to begin with...

Comment: @Matthieu M. Changed the code a bit to insert at different point each time, is this any better?

Comment: I think the code still has two problems: 1) You should probably clear the map between the loops, since the way it is now only the first loop will actually `insert` anything 2) creating a `stringstream` is pretty expensive, so this might influence the measurements. `std::to_string` might be a less impact option (I'm not entirely sure if that has an impact considering the final mapsize, but better be sure).

Comment: @Grizzly Modified it to reflect your suggestions and redid the test.

Comment: I'm not sure I trust this method of testing. I get that 2) is fastest with 9946 ms and 5) longest with 14557 ms. 1,3,4) are all about 10000 ms, same as 2).

Comment: the problem of this testing is the CPU caching too. the latest would be "always" perform slightly better than the first one. you should run those in different processes to benchmark better.

Answer (score 0):

The third one is the best choice (IMHO), but 2, 3 and 4 are equal.

```
// 3) Assignment using member function insert() and "value_type()"
Foo.insert(map<string,int>::value_type("Bar", 12345));
```

Why I think the third one is the best choice: You're performing *only one* operation to insert the value: just inserting (well, there's a search too) and you can know if the value was inserted, checking the `second` member of the return value and the implementation grants to not overwrite the value.

The use of the `value_type` has advantages too: you don't need to know the mapped type or key type so is useful with template programming.

The worst (IMHO) is the first one:

```
// 1) Assignment using array index notation
Foo["Bar"] = 12345;
```

You're calling the `std::map::operator[]` wich creates an object and returns a reference to it, then the mapped object `operator =` is called. You're doing two operations for the insertion: first the insertion, second the asignation.

And it have another problem: you don't know if the value has been inserted or overwrited.

Comment: How is `3)` faster than `2)` ?

Comment: They're equivalent (as said in other answers) I've only focused on wich one is _the best_... so i guess that I've missed this point on my answer.

Comment: 2,3,4 could be equal, provided a good optimizer. However in the non optimized case 3) should be the fastest, since 2) and 4) both incur an additional type conversion to `std::pair<const std::string, int>`.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no object at that key location, then:

[`std::map::emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) is most efficient.  `insert` is second (but will be extremely close).  `[]` is least efficient.

`[]`, if there is no object there, trivial constructs one.  It then calls `operator=`.

`insert` does a copy constructor call on the `std::pair` argument.

However, in the case of maps, `map.insert( make_pair( std::move(key), std::move(value) ) )` is going to be close to `map.emplace( std::move(key), std::move(value) )`.

If there is an object at the key location, then `[]` will call `operator=`, while `insert`/`emplace` will destroy the old object and create a new one.  `[]` could easily be cheaper in this case.

In the end, it depends on what your `operator=` vs copy-construct vs trivial-construct vs destructor costs are for your key and value.

The actual work looking things up within the tree structure of the `std::map` will be so close to identical it isn't funny.