# Populating map in a different way

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

This an existing code that populates a map.

```
typedef unordered_map<std::string, SomeSet> StringToSetMap;

StringToSetMap myMap;

std::string str ("hello");

SomeSet &mySet = myMap[str]; //Map populates here
```

"SomeSet" is a typedefed unordered_set.

Maps as I know can be populated only in the ways mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218042/most-efficient-way-to-assign-values-to-maps)

How is this populating the map this way?

Comment: What about the answer on the question you link to makes what is going on here unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See the docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) for the subscript operator in question. Note that the description of the operator is that it...

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key,
>   performing an insertion if such key does not already exist

Also note:

> **Return value**
>
> Reference to the mapped value of the new element if no element with key key
>   existed. Otherwise a reference to the mapped value of the existing element
>   whose key is equivalent to key.

"hello" is not a key in your map, so it gets inserted and a reference to a shiny new `SomeSet` object is returned to you.

(Note: the key is either move-constructed or copy-constructed, but either way the value is always default constructed. Make sure you have a default constructor for `SomeSet`!)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the inserted element will be default-constructed, and also therefore the subscript operator can only be used if your map is to a type that has a default constructor.

Comment: @scohe001 So I could also populate mySet first and then do `myMap[str] = mySet`. Is that correct?

Comment: @ontherocks Sure. `myMap[str]` returns a reference to the new `SomeSet` object, and then you set it equal to something. it's equivalent to `SomeSet &thing = myMap[str]; thing = mySet;`